# Read Squid access.log with Splunk

Tags: splunk, squid, splunk-query

I'm trying to create a Splunk dashboard with the results of my squid access.log web traffic.
My problem here is, I cant make any search with the results of access.log, which looks for example like this:

2020-10-17 15:41:37  86 192.168.1.41 NONE/200 0 CONNECT twitter.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/104.244.42.193 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0" "SQUID-CS" 209 -

Do you have any suggestions on how I can regex or split the results of these results? I just wanna get the destination URL (twitter.com).

I have a squid index and a squid sourcetype... fyi.

Any tips are appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which of the [Splunkbase Squid apps](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/apps/#/search/squid/) are you running: [Add-On](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2965/#/details), [TA-squid](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1630/), or [App](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/453/#/details)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the `props.conf` settings for the squid sourcetype?  They will help us determine why you have no extracted fields.  If you don't have anything in props.conf for the sourcetype, create some using `access_combined` (find it in $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/default/props.conf) as a model.

To extract just the URL using regex, try this command.

```
... | rex "CONNECT (?<URL>[^:]+)"
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm learning Splunk right now and don't really have a lot of experience with props.conf, but I'll surely have a look and try to find how to configure this config file... thank you!

Comment: Because I don't have any Splunk apps for Squid installed I only have props.conf from the original Splunk installation... I don't believe there are any apps for squid compatible with Splunk 8.0...

Comment: This app claims compatibility with Splunk 8: https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2965/ .  When it comes to props.conf files, compatibility is rarely a problem. At the very least, you can use the configurations in the app as a guide for your own config.

Comment: There are at least 3 apps for squid and I have tried these a lot of time(few days till now) install, uninstall, install again and so one... I can’t make it works, it's annoying because there are also not a lot of resources out there to know how to configure this kind of apps...

Comment: There are few key things to know about installing apps. 1) They're not always the answer.  Some apps work for a specific product version, but not others. 2) Depending on the nature of the app, it may only work on new data and not on data already indexed. 3) Apps can be modified.  Feel free to adjust the settings in an app to match your needs or data. 4) Make sure the sourcetype used by the app matches your data.  If it doesn't then make changes.